# Get a message if checkbox selected only for the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I want to execute a function if a checkbox is selected only for the first time. Is it possible?

By using:

```
this.on('buuttonCheckBox:set', function(){
  //do the work
 })
```

or

```
this.on('buuttonCheckBox:change', function(){
  //do the work
 })
```

or with Jquery:

```
  $('#checkbox1').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        return confirm("Are you sure?");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the box starts out unchecked, use [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) (not that's `one`, not `on`). It attaches an event handler that it removes on the first event.

Try ticking, then unticking, then ticking this:

```js
$("#cb").one("click", function() {
  console.log("First and only notification");
});
```

```html
<label><input id="cb" type="checkbox"> Click me</label>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Alternately, of course, just keep track; jQuery's [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) is a handy way to do that:

```js
$("#cb").on("click", function() {
  console.log("Clicked");
  var $this = $(this);
  if (this.checked && !$this.data("seen")) {
    $this.data("seen", true);
    console.log("The one and only notification");
  }
});
```

```html
<label><input id="cb" type="checkbox"> Click me</label>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement a boolean variable which will keep information if it was already checked or not.

```js
var wasChecked = false;
$('#checkbox1').click(function() {
    if (!wasChecked) {
        alert("Are you sure?");
        wasChecked = true;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox1'>
```

Answer (score 1):

add an *EventListener* function for *change* event and inside the function, remove the *EventListener*

```js
function one(){
  document.getElementById('checkbox1').removeEventListener('change',one);
  return confirm("Are you sure");
}
document.getElementById('checkbox1').addEventListener('change',one);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="Check" />
```